# Calling a Vue mixin directly with a constant?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I have a footer component with three links. When a user clicks a link, besides taking the user to a new page, I am trying to use a mixin to track the click event. When I set a breakpoint in chrome devtools, it appears that this implementation is not working. I imported my constants file, and the mixin.

### footer, one link for brevity

```
  <template>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col align-center">
          <a
            href="/"
            target="_blank"
            class="btn"
            name="item"
            @click="logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.ITEM)">{{ $t('footer.item') }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>
<script>
import analytics from '@/mixins/analytics'
import { ANALYTICS } from "@/constants"

export default {
  name: 'PageFooter',
  mixins: [analytics]
}
</script>
```

### mixin

```
 methods: {
    logButtonClick (buttonType) { // breakpoint here, get nothing
      this.$analytics.track({
        identifier: `Consumer ${this.$options.name} - ${buttonType} Button`
      })
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something? Should this implementation work or should I have a method such as:

```
methods: {
selectLink(str) {
  if (str === item) {
    this.logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.ITEM)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original error I received was

"Property or method `ANALYTICS` not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class based components, by initializing the property."

and

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `ITEM` of undefined at click event...."

Essentially this means I did not define ANALYTICS either in PageFooter (because this is a dumb component, I did not want to add a data object to it, I wanted to keep it strictly presentational) or on the vue instance at a root level. Since ANALYTICS is undefined, ITEM then throws another error because it can not be a property of undefined.

This is my solution, I used a switch case in the   and in the template  tag added **@click="selectLink('asd')**"

```
methods: {
    selectLink (str) {
      switch (true) {
        case str === 'asd':
          this.logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.ITEM)
          break
        case str === 'efg':
          this.logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.ITEM2)
          break
        case str === 'hij':
          this.logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.ITEM3)
          break
      }
    }
  }
```

and the unit test:

```
it('[positive] should track analytics if `asd` is passed to selectLink()', () => {
    const str = 'asd'
    const mockFn = jest.fn()
    jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'logButtonClick')
    wrapper.find('a').trigger('click')
    mockFn(str)


expect(wrapper.vm.logButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ANALYTICS.COOKIE_CONSENT)
      })
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties

Moral of the story, question things when senior engineers tell you to do something funky in a code review.